# The stream or file \"/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log\" could not be opened in append mode... Permission denied. gcp "Cloud run"

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, devops, google-cloud-run

FROM php:8.0-apache-buster

#install all the system dependencies and enable PHP modules
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y 
libpq-dev 
libzip-dev 
&& rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/* 
&& docker-php-ext-install 
pdo_pgsql 
pgsql 
zip

#install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer

#change uid and gid of apache to docker user uid/gid
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data && groupmod -g 1000 www-data

#change the web_root to laravel /var/www/html/public folder
RUN sed -i -e "s/html/html/public/g" /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

## enable apache module rewrite

RUN a2enmod rewrite

#copy source files and run composer
COPY . /var/www/html

## install all PHP dependencies

RUN cd /var/www/html

RUN composer install --no-interaction

RUN composer update

RUN composer dump-autoload
#change ownership of our applications
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/storage

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache

RUN chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/storage

RUN chmod -R 777 bootstrap

RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html

ENTRYPOINT ["/var/www/html/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

These are the above commands I added in my dockerfile to avoid permission error
but the issue is when i run this dockerfile in my local system it works fine for the application
but when i deploy on cloud run and enter the wrong login info into my application it gives me this error " "message": "The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied","
So I believe there is no issue in the dockerfile may be some issue inthe configuration of cloud run. I don't know

**apache2.conf**

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public/

  <Directory /var/www/html/>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: add APP_DEBUG=true and APP_KEY under variable and secrets and it should work

Comment: Edit your question and show the <Directory> entry in apache2.conf for the laravel/public entry. If you do not have one, add one. Laravel requires **AllowOverride All**

Comment: I have updated my question please have a look 
changed to AllowOverride All 
but still the same issue

Comment: You also do not have <Directory> for **html/public**

Comment: where I have to add <Directory> for html/public
000-default.conf or apache2.conf

Comment: Always try to read the documentation for details like this. apache2.conf

Answer (score 0):

Try following commands in the root of your project directory.

`find . -type d -print0 |xargs -0 chmod 755`

`find . -type f -print0 |xargs -0 chmod 644`

Also you can try following

**nginx.dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:stable-alpine

ADD ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
ADD ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html
RUN addgroup -g 1000 laravel && adduser -G laravel -g laravel -s /bin/sh -D laravel
RUN chown laravel:laravel /var/www/html
```

**php.dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

ADD ./php/www.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/

RUN apt update && apt install -y curl libonig-dev libxml2-dev unzip zlib1g-dev libpng-dev zip libzip-dev && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN addgroup --gid 1000 laravel && adduser --ingroup  laravel --gecos laravel --shell /bin/sh --disabled-password laravel
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html
RUN chown laravel:laravel /var/www/html

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql gd zip bcmath mbstring exif pcntl
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! but as I said I am running cloud run service so I cannot ssh the server for the production
but i applied these commands to /var/www/html after exec into my local running container and these commands run successfully and in response provide me nothing

Comment: Give group write access to /storage/logs/ in dockerfile


*`chmod g+w storage/logs`*

Comment: I have updated my question 
Please have a look 
Added Docker file

Comment: I have updated the answer see if this can help you. i have attached sample of nginx.dockerfile and php.dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone who helped me
The issue has been fixed.
In my laravel directory owner of the every folder was www-data except /logs
So I added the command saparately to change the owner of /logs